# search text in other text and highlight it using javascript

Tags: javascript

find text in given in textbox on buttonclick in html static page.and then hightlight it using javascript

Answer (score 5):

Here's an Example With Code from **[Searching for Text In Page](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/searchin.htm)**. It essentially performs the equivalent of doing a **Find** with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> in in the browser. If you use the [jQuery](http://jquery.com) library, you can use the [Search-Highlight Plugin](http://www.jquery.info/The-plugin-SearchHighlight) to highlight the text in a similar way to what Google search does.

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
var TRange=null;
function findString (str) {
 if (parseInt(navigator.appVersion)<4) return;
 var strFound;
 if (window.find) {

  // CODE FOR BROWSERS THAT SUPPORT window.find
  strFound=self.find(str);
  if (strFound && self.getSelection && !self.getSelection().anchorNode) {
   strFound=self.find(str)
  }
  if (!strFound) {
   strFound=self.find(str,0,1)
   while (self.find(str,0,1)) continue
  }
 }
 else if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft")!=-1) {

  // EXPLORER-SPECIFIC CODE

  if (TRange!=null) {
   TRange.collapse(false)
   strFound=TRange.findText(str)
   if (strFound) TRange.select()
  }
  if (TRange==null || strFound==0) {
   TRange=self.document.body.createTextRange()
   strFound=TRange.findText(str)
   if (strFound) TRange.select()
  }
 }
 else if (navigator.appName=="Opera") {
  alert ("Opera browsers not supported, sorry...")
  return;
 }
 if (!strFound) alert ("String '"+str+"' not found!")
 return;
}
//-->
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="f1" action="" 
    onSubmit="if(this.t1.value!=null && this.t1.value!='') findString(this.t1.value);return false">
    <input type="text" name=t1 value="" size=20>
    <input type="submit" name=b1 value="Find">
    <p>This is some sample text.</p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <form id=f1 name="f1" action="" 
onSubmit="if(this.t1.value!=null && this.t1.value!='')
findString(this.t1.value);return false"
>
<input type="text" id=t1 name=t1size=20>
<input type="submit" name=b1 value="Find">
</form>
<script>
var TRange=null;

function findString (str) {
 if (parseInt(navigator.appVersion)<4) return;
 var strFound;
 if (window.find) {

  // CODE FOR BROWSERS THAT SUPPORT window.find

  strFound=self.find(str);
  if (!strFound) {
   strFound=self.find(str,0,1);
   while (self.find(str,0,1)) continue;
  }
 }
 else if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft")!=-1) {

  // EXPLORER-SPECIFIC CODE

  if (TRange!=null) {
   TRange.collapse(false);
   strFound=TRange.findText(str);
   if (strFound) TRange.select();
  }
  if (TRange==null || strFound==0) {
   TRange=self.document.body.createTextRange();
   strFound=TRange.findText(str);
   if (strFound) TRange.select();
  }
 }
 else if (navigator.appName=="Opera") {
  alert ("Opera browsers not supported, sorry...")
  return;
 }
 if (!strFound) alert ("String '"+str+"' not found!")
 return;
}
</script>
```