# Hightlighting a particular text dynamically on the screen using smartGwt

Tags: smartgwt, smartgwt-pro

I Have an implemented a search screen ,  like hows it done in the windows but im not able to highlight the text for which search was made.

i tried to use window.find ()  but its not available in smartgwt

Answer (score 0):

If I were with such request I would probably go for a jsni function and some sort of code like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857079/search-text-in-other-text-and-highlight-it-using-javascript)..... or using javaScript text [higlighting](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html) jQuery plugin. I don't think there is neither in gwt or smartgwt such a feature...